# Thevenin impedance problem

Tags: ac, impedance, h-bridge, thevenin

I've tried to find the Thevenin impedance of this configuration but I keep getting wrong answers.

My idea was to look at it as a double delta configuration, convert the upper delta to on y and carry our the series and parallel additions like followsm

1. I obtained the sum of the three upper impedances: 10 - 5j.
2. Za = - 25j/(10-5j) = Zb.  Zc = 25/(10-5j).
3. I added Zc + j5 = Z_(left) = 2+6j and Zb + 5 = Z_(right) = 3- j.
4. [ Z_(left) * Z_(right) ] / [ Z_(left) + Z_(right) ] = Zp = 14/5 + 4j
5. Zp + Za = Ztf = 4/5 +3j [image]

What Im missing ?

EDIT:

Method: [image]

Calculation: [image]

Comment: Please give more details, it's unclear what your variables refer to

Comment: I don't follow your methodology. I do understand what you mean when you say "double delta". Or I think I do for a moment. Then upon reading the rest I know that I honestly didn't know what you meant. So I'm stopped now. What techniques are you familiar with using? Do you know KCL (nodal?) Do you know KVL (mesh?) Or is this some kind of phasor approach? What's the deal?

Comment: Sorry. I've posted my whole method and calculation by editting the post. I'm familiar with every technique you've mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: @Vladnerovski Okay. So, using KCL and grounding node b, I find the voltage at the left node is 50+j50 and the voltage at the right node is also 50+j50. I also find the voltage for node a is 100. So there should be no net current (the average, I mean) through the bridging 5 Ohm resistor. Same result if all I do is remove the bridging 5 Ohm for a moment and work out the voltage divider for the remaining left and right legs.

Comment: Here's a full nodal (KCL) solved without any simplifying assumptions: `solve( [ Eq( n1/5 + n1/5/I + n1/5, n3/5 + n2/5 ), Eq( n2/5 + n2/5 - n2/5/I, -n3/5/I + n1/5 ), Eq( n3/5 - n3/5/I, n1/5 - n2/5/I + 20 ) ], [ n1, n2, n3 ] ) ==> { n1: 50 + 50*I, n2: 50 + 50*I, n3: 100 }` Did I mess up? For dividers, left and right: `simplify( 5*I / (5+5*I) ) ==> 1/2 + I/2` and `simplify( 5 / (5-5*I) ) ==> 1/2 + I/2`. If node a is 100, then similar results for the left and right node voltages result.

Comment: +1 for showing your work.

Comment: @periblepsis. Yeah I understand this principle now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given network is powered by an independent current generator. This current is divided into the two branches. I have applied Thevenin's theorem twice.
[image]

Comment: Interesting method and nice way to practice Thevenin's theorem. Thank you very much!